# Rollback of sql query in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table:

```
create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "mobile"
    t.text     "social_media"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "type"
    t.text     "subtype"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "priority"
    t.integer  "responsible"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.boolean  "payed",        default: false
    t.datetime "date"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
  end
```

note, I have deleted all constraints, like not null etc.
and I have method:

```
def mark_payed
    @request.update(payed: true)
    redirect_to requests_path 
end
```

so I want to update payed boolean attribute to true.
When i update request object with name defined like this one:(note: the name attribute is set)

```
2530;"ТОО ББ Нура";"---;--;-";;"---";"---";"";"";3;"";"---";"2";13;3000;FALSE;"";"2015-06-09 00:00:00";"2015-06-17 06:59:49.621709"
```

it works fine and my payed attribute is updated.

But in when i am updating this one: (note: the name attribute is empty ('').)

```
2532;"''";"''";89;"''";"''";"";"";3;"";"-";"2";2;1200;FALSE;"";"2015-06-09 00:00:00";"2015-06-16 11:18:54.296975"
```

I get a ROLLBACK.

HERE ARE THE LOGS FOR TWO CASES:
CASE 1:

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Request Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2533]]
  Request Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2533]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "requests" SET "social_media" = $1, "subtype" = $2, "payed" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "requests"."id" = $5  [["social_media", nil], ["subtype", nil], ["payed", "t"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-17 08:50:45.921870"], ["id", 2533]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "requests" SET "social_media" = $1, "subtype" = $2, "payed" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "requests"."id" = $5  [["social_media", nil], ["subtype", nil], ["payed", "t"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-17 08:50:45.921870"], ["id", 2533]]
   (8.7ms)  COMMIT
   (8.7ms)  COMMIT
```

CASE 2:

```
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Request Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2532]]
  Request Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2532]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
```

So i get rollback in the update query. Also if it makes sense I have an before_update: update_attributes which finds_by client_id.
Notice, that client_id is null in first case, which works,
and is set in second case which doesn't. So I concluded that it is not due to before_update.

Also it is kind of strange to see logs doubled, but it is out of scope of my question for now.

EDIT: my before_update action (btw, i commented out before_update, the problem is same)

```html
def update_attributes
 @client = Client.find_by(client_id: self.client_id) if self.client_id.present?

 if @client.present?
  filled_cartridges.each do |d|
   @r = FilledCartridge.find_by(request_id: d.id)
   @cartridge = Cartridge.find_by(cartridge_name: d.cartridge_name)
   if @cartridge.nil?
    @cartridge = Cartridge.create!(cartridge_name: d.cartridge_name)
       end
       d.client_id = @client.id
       d.cartridge_id = @cartridge.id
      end
     end
     # update repair_cartridges attributes
    end
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your `before_update`?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're doing, but in the second line of semicolon-separated fields, some fields contain `"''"`, which is not empty, but is the string `''`, so you're trying to save a string in an integer database field.

Comment: @vmarquet, no checked it. '' is stored only in character varying cells. integers are in integer cells.

Comment: @vmarquet, what about case 1 logs, in update statement, notice that social_media etc fields are being updated too, but i only call update on payed attribute. Can it be the problem place?

Comment: Yes, this is very weird. The fact that each line appears twice in the log is weird too. You say you removed all constraints, but have you also removed all callbacks on models?

Comment: @vmarquet, aaah. that's was it. I created validations. Then i had to migrate old db where many fields are empty, therefore do not pass. I though I will be notified if validations will not pass.